# System function in C language - creating user from CodeBlocks (C) program

Tags: c

I have a problem, i wanted to do a program which will be used to make an account on PC. I write from keyboard name and password which is used to create new user. Everything was okey to the time when i wanted to write command in code, I used "system("net user xxx /add")" where xxx == name of the new user, yes it is working like that, but i want to change xxx to the variable which is written from the keyboard. I mean that, the name of the new user which is creating, the user of program will choose. Any help?

```
int main()
{

char login; 



printf("Login of the new user:");

scanf("%s",&login);  

system("net user xxx /add"); 



return 0;  
}
```

Comment: may be `system(sprintf("net user %s /add", &login))`

Comment: `char login; ... scanf("%s",&login);` is "working" only for very low standards of "working".  It's in fact undefined behavior because the `scanf()` format `%s` is for reading a nul-terminated string - but `login` is merely a single `char` and can't hold a string at all.

Comment: @shibormot `sprintf` does *not* return the string it produces!

Comment: @GovindParmar ok, its c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `sprintf` to build a string. It works similar to `printf` but produces its output in a character array rather than as output to `stdout`.

For example:

```
char buffer[100], login[100];
printf("Login of the new user: ");
scanf("%s", login); // notice there is no & operator here
sprintf(buffer, "net user %s /add", login);
system(buffer);
```

Safer code would use `snprintf`, which also takes the length of the destination character array as a parameter to ensure that it does not overflow.  Also, I'd use `fgets` rather than `scanf` as it is inherently safer for the same reason that `snprintf` is safer than `sprintf`.

As a side note, for what you're trying to do (add a new user on a Windows system), [there are Windows APIs specifically designed for that purpose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370649(v=vs.85).aspx) that you should use rather than calling the net command from `system`, because these methods will indicate success and failure of attempting to add the user. I concede that there is a very steep learning curve to the Windows API, but if it lets you avoid using the `system` function, it really is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you do not`scanf` towards a variable which is only 1 byte (`login`). This will just result in buffer overflow and application crash. Since I have the feeling that this is a homework kind of assignment I recommend using an array of chars with help from [Since we have snprintf, why we don't have a snscanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368712/since-we-have-snprintf-why-we-dont-have-a-snscanf). Otherwise, this answer: [C - scanf() vs gets() vs fgets()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302255/c-scanf-vs-gets-vs-fgets/3302594#3302594) will give some good directions on how to read (more) safely from the stdin.

Secondly you will need another buffer for creating the `net add ...` command. For this I recommend using `snprintf` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93.aspx) in order to achieve the desired result in a safe manner.

Intentionally I do not post code here to solve this problem, in order to not to hinder your learning, feel free to ask more questions.