# Reading directly on the terminal

Tags: c

I am trying to write in a file from a terminal until you write "exit". This code copiles, but doesn't work. It doesn't even write a file ! What should I do?

```
void            my_script(char* name, t_Option option)
{
  FILE          *file;

  (void)option;
  while (strcmp("/stdin", "exit") != 0)
    {
      file = NULL;
      file = fopen(name,"w");
      fprintf(file, "%s", "Writing in a file !\n");
      fclose(file);
    }
}
```

Tanks for your help! :)

/***********************************/

Here is my solution, tanks to you guys, who reminded me a lot ;)

```
void            my_script(char* name)
{
  FILE          *file;
  char          buff[4096];
  int           len;

  file = NULL;
  len = 0;
  file = fopen(name,"w");
  while ((len = read(0, buff, 4096)) != -1)
    {
      buff[len] = '\0';
      if (strncmp(buff, "exit", 4) == 0)
        break;
      fprintf(file, "%s", buff);
    }
  fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Besides the problem with reading the terminal input which is answered below, there should be no reason to not write the file. Are you sure you are actually calling the `my_script()` function? And with a correct value for `name`?

Comment: What if you write ` exit` with a space before or after the word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FILE *file = fopen(name, "w");
char buff[BUFSIZ];
while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin) && strcmp(buff, "exit\n")){
    fprintf(file, "%s", buff);
}
fclose(file);
```

Comment: I'm okay with accepting but an explanation could have been great.. otherwise he's going to copy-paste this and learn nothing.

Comment: Huh level that can be fully understood if you look at the reference.

Comment: Oh well, I suppose it works for the user. +1 by me, I didn't think of the fgets in the first place and unleashed Daniel's hell :)

Answer (score -1):

You need a console input function like [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) to **read from the standard input and then store the read input into an array** or something similar:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char text[100];   
  do {
    printf("Enter text : \n");                              
    scanf_s("%s", text, 100);
  } while(strcmp(text, "exit"));

  return 0;
}
```

in your code

```
strcmp("/stdin", "exit")
```

is basically asking

> are '/stdin' and 'exit' the same characters?

and the answer will always be the same: no. And the loop will always be entered and never left.

Comment: *"So the loop is never entered."* - Why? The return value of `strcmp("/stdin", "exit")` is not equal to zero, which means that the while-loop *is* entered.

Comment: Right, there's a != 0, I'll fix it!

Comment: -1. This has a potential buffer overflow at `scanf("%s", text);`.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar He doesn't know how to read from it, besides you might not be aware that http://stackoverflow.com/a/9457391/1938163 . Anyway I'll use a safe version specific to Ms compilers.

Comment: I think I just died a little inside.