# In C, how to find the number of space within the input line by the user?

Tags: c, space

I'd like to know how to detect the number of spaces within the line that is entered by the user? The `scanf` function that I am using is:

```
scanf (" %[^\n]s", &line[0])
```

Here `line` is my `char` variable.

Am I doing any mistake?

Comment: Other than a buffer overflow vulnerability I could drive a truck through, no :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could count the spaces, given that you manage to successfully read the input:

```
uint spaces = 0;
size_t len = strlen(line);
for (size_t idx=0; idx<len; ++idx)
   if (line[idx] == ' ')
      ++spaces;
```

And BTW, take a look at these threads:

[Max string length using scanf -> ANSI C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314796/max-string-length-using-scanf-ansi-c)

[How to use sscanf correctly and safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457325/how-to-use-sscanf-correctly-and-safely)

scanf is not your best buddy

Comment: Using strlen is not very efficient. If your string has length n, strlen will be called n times.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yep, but I've written a quick answer, now it is improved

Answer (score 0):

```
int countspaces(const char *str)
{
  int count = 0 ;
  char c ;
  while((c = *str++) != 0)
  {
    if (c == ' ')
      count++ ;
  }

  return count ;
}

...
scanf (" %[^\n]s", &line[0])
int nbofspaces = countspaces(line) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following program will print the number of spaces in a string.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    void main(void)
    {
        char *input_string;
        unsigned int space_counter = 0;
        scanf("%[^\n]",input_string);
        while(input_string != '\0')
        {
           if(*input_string == ' ')//check whether the char is space
              space_counter++      //increment space counter

           input_string++;         //increment counter
        }
        printf("Number of spaces in the string=%d",space_counter);
    }
```