# How to assign a char an int value?

Tags: c, struct, char, int

I'm trying to make a solitaire game using structs and linked lists, I've started with reading cards from a file with colours and it's values, so I have a problem with such cards as '`A`', '`J`', '`D`', '`K`'
their values are to be set to `1, 11, 12, 13` respectively. How do I do this in case of using following construction:

```
    #define J 11

    typedef struct card {
    char color[15];
    unsigned int value;
    struct card* pnext;
    struct card* pprev;
} cardsStruct;

struct card* pstart = NULL;
struct card* plast = NULL;

int main()
{
    FILE *myFile;
    cardsStruct card;
    if ((myFile = fopen("Cards.txt", "rb")) == NULL)
        return -1;
    while (!feof(myFile)){
        fscanf(myFile, "%s %u", card.color, &card.value);
        printf("%s %u\n", card.color, card.value);
    }
    fclose(myFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about hexadecimal numbers? There are 16 of them :-)

Comment: Any number in decimal or hexadecimal. You can define them as macros.

Comment: See second answer there as you have a lots issues here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c?sort=frequent&pageSize=15

Comment: Couple different approaches you could take. You could have `char face[10];` and `unsigned int pts;` - that's probably the easiest. Then treat every read and write as text.

Comment: If you mean something like  #define A 2, it doesn't work here

Comment: Why it doesn't work?

Comment: You will want to look at [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: Well, you cant use char for representation, I mean not 6 but '6' etc. Then no problems with 'K', 'A', etc.

Comment: You write, that you have a problem there. However, to me, it is not quite clear what problem you are actually asking about. Can you clarify this?

Comment: The problem is that I can't find a way to assign to, for example, 'J' card an int value of '11'

Comment: Where is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In **C**, you can try to *simulate the feel of maps from C++*...

```
int characters[128] = {0};
characters['A'] = 1;
characters['J'] = 11;
characters['D'] = 12;
characters['K'] = 13;
```

And print it like this:

```
printf("%s %u\n", card.color, characters['K']);
```

Comment: You've specifically not initialized the array, so other characters will contain garbage now

Answer (score 0):

you need three forms of holding the cards:

- In the text file
- for program use
- When displaying

I think the trick here is to do conversions. 
For example, in the file it is nicer to use letters (A,J,D/Q,K) so it will be human readable and also easy to edit.
when displaying, you want it also to be human readable.
In RAM, for program use, you better use an hexadecimal values so it will be easy to do calculations.

Comment: Yeah, the cards will be held in the text file as for example "RED J", the rules are as in classic solitaire, where you can only put a card on acard with a value bigger by 1,  for example "3 on 4", "10 on J", to make this possible I need to make 'J' into '11'

Comment: No, not only in printing I'm going to use 'J' for user input command like "move red J to 4" and then it should compare card's value with the last card in fourth stack, whether the difference is 1 or not, how would it compare J to 10?

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(card)
{
  case 'A':
     value = 1;
     break;
  case 'J':
     value = 11;
     break;
  /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[In a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53865147/how-to-assign-a-char-an-int-value#comment94578083_53865294) you wrote:

> the cards will be held in the text file as for example "RED J"

Obviously, you can't parse a letter with a format specifier for an unsigned integer.

So this is wrong:

> ```
> fscanf(myFile, "%s %u", card.color, &card.value);
> ```

I suggest you read the file line wise (using `fgets()` or `getline()`), and try to parse it afterwards, e.g. using `sscanf()`. So if this fails to parse the number `sscanf(in, "%14s %u", out)`, you can try to parse `"%14s %c"` afterwards.

A few other suggestions:

- Don't mix the implementation of the linked list and the data type.
- Define a different type to hold the list, than to represent the list node.
- Split functionality in functions, especially taking input and parsing input.
- Check and handle errors consistently.
- Decouple the file representation of a card and the data representation in your program.
- Create a function for deserialization, i.e., to convert the suit and rank strings to enum values or defined integer literals.
- Create a function to convert suit to color, instead of storing a color string directly.
- If you are new to C, then maybe it makes sense to work out the business logic in another simpler language first and then port it to C.

For reference and further reading:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets
- https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf
- [Read .CSV file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911299/read-csv-file-in-c)
- [How to use sscanf correctly and safely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9457325/1025391)